# Sharing/exporting map created in QGIS for different people in Company?

Tags: qgis, export, google-earth-pro, cloud-gis

I created a QGIS map with several different layers. 
I want to know a light way method to share it locally with staff. If I can be pointed to the different export formats that may work for me in Qgis. I can experiment and see what may work
The map has to be able to display certain attribute features when a certain layer is clicked. 
I exported it as a kml file. But it is very large and slow.

[image: Project screen image]

Comment: "Best" questions don't fare well here, since *opinion-based* questions are not allowed. Please take the [Tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) to better understand how our "Focused question / Best answer" model works.